# Powershell: Edit the drive letter of all my shortcuts that begin with X:\

Tags: powershell, shortcut, com-interop, powershell-4.0, path-manipulation

I have a situation where all the paths in the shortcut files that are located in the `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` folder and subfolders all point to an incorrect drive letter. This includes the *Target:* value, *Start In:* value and all the paths to the icon files as well. I'd like to change them all from `X:\` to `C:\`

There are a couple that are correctly pointing to `C:\` but there's only a handful of them.

Here is the code I was working with. I am able to change the `TargetPath` but not the `WorkingDirectory` value. I've tried removing the comment on line 20 but that creates an error about `$null`-valued expression. I've also tried duplicating the bit for `TargetPath` to `WorkingDirectory` but it does not change:

```
$folder = "C:\Temp\Shortcuts" 
[string]$from = "X:\" 
[string]$to = "C:\" 
$list = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Recurse  | Where-Object { $_.Attributes -ne "Directory"} | select -ExpandProperty FullName 
$obj = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell 

ForEach($lnk in $list) 
{ 
    $obj = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell 
    $link = $obj.CreateShortcut($lnk) 
    [string]$path = $link.TargetPath  
    [string]$path = [string]$path.Replace($from.tostring(),$to.ToString()) 
#   [string]$path = $link.WorkingDirectory
#   [string]$path = [string]$path.Replace($from.tostring(),$to.ToString()) 

    #If you need workingdirectory change please uncomment the below line. 
    #$link.WorkingDirectory = [string]$WorkingDirectory.Replace($from.tostring(),$to.ToString()) 
    $link.TargetPath = [string]$path 
    $link.Save() 
}
```

Comment: Did you tried something on your own. Do you have some code you have problems with? So is not a code writing service

Comment: try to short your code and show us your problem. Otherwise no one will help you

Comment: It appears that the trouble I'm experiencing is related to case. In my shortcuts the TargetPath is set with upper-case drive letter, the WorkingDirectory is set using lower-case. I cannot seem to find the correct way to express case-insensitivity to the .Replace command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 20 in the code you posted is the trailing `}`, but I'm assuming this...

```
#$link.WorkingDirectory = [string]$WorkingDirectory.Replace($from.tostring(),$to.ToString())
```

...is the real line 20.  The reason for that error is because you are trying to call `.Replace()` on `$WorkingDirectory` instead of `$link.WorkingDirectory`.  `$WorkingDirectory`, if it's not set anywhere, will evaluate to `$null`.

With that corrected, PowerShell provides its own [string replacement operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#replacement-operator): `-replace` and `-ireplace` are case-insensitive, `-creplace` is case-sensitive.  The first operand to all of these operators is a [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions), and since a backslash in regex denotes a special character, you will need to escape the `\` in your search pattern like this...

```
[string]$from = "X:\\"
```

You can then change the drive letter of the `WorkingDirectory` property with...

```
$link.WorkingDirectory = [string] $link.WorkingDirectory -replace $from.tostring(),$to.ToString()
```

...or...

```
$link.WorkingDirectory = [string] $link.WorkingDirectory -ireplace $from.tostring(),$to.ToString()
```

Note that `$link.WorkingDirectory`, `$from`, and `$to` are already of type `[String]`, so the `[String]` cast and calls to `.ToString()` are unnecessary and can be removed...

```
$link.WorkingDirectory = $link.WorkingDirectory -replace $from,$to
```

One tiny optimization you might make is to add an [anchor](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions) to your search pattern so it won't bother to search for the drive letter beyond the absolute beginning of the `[String]`...

```
[string]$from = "^X:\\"
```

Also, since you are using PowerShell 3+, instead of filtering out directories like this...

```
$list = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Recurse  | Where-Object { $_.Attributes -ne "Directory"}
```

...you can filter *in* files [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/providers/filesystem-provider/get-childitem-for-filesystem)...

```
$list = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Recurse -File
```

Better yet, you can use the `-Filter` parameter to only include files with an `.lnk` extension, too...

```
$list = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Recurse -File -Filter '*.lnk'
```

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the extra information you provided, it's given me a lot of information I wasn't able to understand from the original script. Much appreciated. I do have a bit of a problem with one adjustment. 

The code line:    
    `$list = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Recurse -File -Filter '*.lnk' `
creates the correct list but the code:
    `$link = $obj.CreateShortcut($lnk)`
replaces the $folder with "C:\Windows\System32" so instead of a filename “C:\Temp\Shortcut\FileName.lnk” I get “C:\Windows\System32\Filename.lnk”
@bacon

Comment: When you pass `$lnk` of type [`FileInfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo) as the `String` parameter to `CreateShortcut()`, PowerShell won't know how to meaningfully convert that so it just calls [`$lnk.ToString()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.tostring).  This returns just the file name, which `.CreateShortcut()` treats as a relative path in the current directory, `C:\Windows\System32`. Instead, pass the shortcut file's path, [`$lnk.FullName`](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname), to `.CreateShortcut()`.

Comment: I'm glad that solved your issue.  Remember that as the question author you can [upvote or downvote answers based on whether you find them helpful or not, and accept an answer that best solves your probem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).